# Swagger Codegen dynamic creation of some models dynamically

Tags: android, ios, swagger, mustache, swagger-codegen

In short, using Swagger I would like the capability to dynamically generate, or not generate a model dependent on an attribute in the yaml.

I have this working with our current generator, but it requires all the classes to be generated in one file, which is obviously not ideal.

A couple vectors I've looked into without any success (without large re-writes at least) are conditionally adding a modelTemplateFile to the CodeGen, removing/not removing some classes during generation, and creating blank files on classes I don't want to generate.

None of these will seem to work quite right without a sizable re-write/additions as it appears this isn't a use case the library is taking into consideration. I'm pretty adverse to writing large amounts of corner-case code on a library that's still evolving, so I'm looking for a clean way to integrate the capability without re-writing/extending core classes.

The environments I'm currently building for are iOS, Android. The reason I want to be able to create/not create models is our current architecture includes both a database model, and a swagger model, with some models being excluded from the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use .swagger-codegen-ignore to skip model files (or other files) that you don't want to generate when using Swagger Codegen.

.swagger-codegen-ignore pretty much works like .gitignore.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I don't see how this applies given my constraints. I need to be able dynamically generate/not generate models depending on attributes in the yaml. My understanding of the ignore is it's for avoiding overwrites and is static. I don't want to have to change the ignore file every time I adjust the API description. Am I missing something?